# hunspell to handle common english verbs contractions for -ing

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell, spelling, misspelling

[Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io/) does not handle by defaults common English Verb contractions of `-ing` like `goin`, `givin`,  `doin`, etc. These verb contractions it seems not to be handled. Let's take an example

```
I'm going to surfin' and livin' on my own and maybe givin' up
```

This will be the hunspell correct, suggestions, analysis (morphological) for this sentence:

```
[
                                {
                                    "word": "I",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "m",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "goin",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [
                                        "goon",
                                        "gin",
                                        "groin",
                                        "going",
                                        "gain",
                                        "grin",
                                        "loin",
                                        "coin",
                                        "gown",
                                        "go in",
                                        "go-in"
                                    ],
                                    "correct": false,
                                    "analysis": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "to",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "surfin",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [
                                        "surfing",
                                        "surf in",
                                        "surf-in",
                                        "superfine"
                                    ],
                                    "correct": false,
                                    "analysis": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "and",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "livin",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [
                                        "living",
                                        "liven",
                                        "livid",
                                        "violin",
                                        "Lin"
                                    ],
                                    "correct": false,
                                    "analysis": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "on",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "my",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "own",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "and",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "maybe",
                                    "stems": [
                                        "maybe"
                                    ],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true,
                                    "analysis": [
                                        " st: maybe"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "givin",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [
                                        "giving",
                                        "given",
                                        "virgin",
                                        "gin"
                                    ],
                                    "correct": false,
                                    "analysis": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "word": "up",
                                    "stems": [],
                                    "suggestion": [],
                                    "correct": true
                                }
                            ]
```

so for contractions like `givin` the correct flag is `false` and there are some suggestions, among them the `-ing` form `giving`. For some reason, the morphological analysis is not present.
So how to add support for English verb forms of verbs followed by `-ing` in order to be considered as correct terms?
Shall be added some rules fo the affix dictionary for English?